# Categories loop with custom field

Tags: categories

I'm trying to display a custom field within a categories loop (Channel Form). The `{category_name}` outputs just fine but ExpressionEngine refuses to render the custom field `{category_custom_field}`. (The custom field does work with `exp:channel:categories`.)

```
{categories show_group="5" parse="inward"}
  <option value="{category_id}" {selected}>
    {category_custom_field}
  </option>
{/categories}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs for the Channel Form](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#categories) custom fields are not loaded.

You mention the solution though, we can wrap the bit where you need the custom field in an `exp:channel:categories` tag so you can load the custom tags. We do it this way so we can preserve the `selected` tags too

```
{categories show_group="5" parse="inward"}
  <option value="{category_id}" {selected}>
      {exp:channel:categories channel="1" style="linear" show="{category_id}"}
        {category_custom_field}
      {/exp:channel:categories}
  </option>
{/categories}
```

*You don't quote what channel the entry form is for so I use 1 in the example above.*

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help Blatant :)